# Inserting array data using mysql insert id and if statements

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, insert, lastinsertid

Ok so whilst I have been working on my PHP and MySQL skills I am new to inserting data into multiple  tables in one go. I have done some reading around the subject and I appreciate the basics and the importance of normalised data etc and as such the need to put the information into various tables.

I have pieced the code below together from some of my previous work as well as the tutorial offered at http://www.desilva.biz/mysql/insertid.html . The issue I currently face is that the tutorial I learnt the code from for inputting into various tables was not based around an array of data and whilst I have got it to almost work I cannot use my fuelrecords_id because where I have to call it in my current code it has not yet been defined. Therefore to make my code work at present I just have to use a comma for the column.

Finally I would like to perfect a way to make the if statements work correctly with the array data so if a 0 or blank is submitted as part of the array a new row is not inserted with just 0's in my database tables for that respective row of data

```
<?php
$wedrf=trim($_POST['FR_WE']);
list($d, $m, $y) = explode('/', $wedrf);
$mk=mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, $d, $y);
$wed_refor=strftime('%Y-%m-%d',$mk);

$con = mysql_connect("ip","username","password");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("jbsrint", $con);

//New Code

$row_data = array(); 
foreach($_POST['VEH_LIST_REG'] as $row=>$VEH_LIST_REG) { 
$WEDATE=$wed_refor;
$VEH_LIST_REG=mysql_real_escape_string($VEH_LIST_REG); 
$FR_DIE_L=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['FR_DIE_L'][$row]); 
$FR_DIE_C=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['FR_DIE_C'][$row]); 
$FR_PET_L=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['FR_PET_L'][$row]); 
$FR_PET_C=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['FR_PET_C'][$row]); 
$FR_OIL_L=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['FR_OIL_L'][$row]); 
$FR_OIL_C=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['FR_OIL_C'][$row]); 
$row_data[] = "(',', '$VEH_LIST_REG', '$WEDATE')"; 
$row_data1[] = "(',','$FR_DIE_L', '$FR_DIE_C', ',')";
$row_data2[] = "(',', '$FR_PET_L', '$FR_PET_C', ',')";
$row_data3[] = "(',', '$FR_OIL_L', '$FR_OIL_C', '$FR_OIL_C')";
} 
if (!empty($row_data)) { 
$query = 'INSERT INTO fuelrecords(FR_ID, VEH_LIST_REG, FR_WE) VALUES '.implode(',', $row_data); 
#$result = mysql_query( $query);

#  get fuelrecord id  
$fuelrecords_ID = mysql_insert_id();

#  if the user submitted diesel information
if( isset($FR_DIE_L) )
{

#  and insert the diesel details
$sql = "INSERT INTO fuelrecords_die(FRD_ID,FR_DIE_L,FR_DIE_C,fuelrecords_ID) VALUES ".implode(',', $row_data1);
$result = mysql_query( $sql);
}

#  if the user submitted petrol information
if( isset($FR_PET_L) )
{

#  and insert the diesel details
$sql = "INSERT INTO fuelrecords_pet(FRP_ID,FR_PET_L,FR_PET_C,fuelrecords_ID) VALUES ".implode(',', $row_data2);
$result = mysql_query( $sql);
}

#  if the user submitted oil information
if( isset($FR_OIL_L) )
{

#  and insert the oil details
$sql = "INSERT INTO fuelrecords_oil(FRO_ID,FR_OIL_L,FR_OIL_C,fuelrecords_ID) VALUES ".implode(',', $row_data3);
$result = mysql_query( $sql);
}

if (mysql_query($query)) 
    echo '<font color=\"FFFFFF\" size=\"3px\">Successful inserted</font>'; 
else 
    echo '<font color=\"FFFFFF\" size=\"3px\">Insert failed</font>'; 
} 

?>

<?php
mysql_close($con)
?>
```

Tables are as follows:

```
fuelrecords 
FR_ID (Auto increment) 
VEH_LIST_REG 
FR_WE 

fuelrecords_die 
FRD_ID (AUTO INCREMENT) 
FR_DIE_L 
FR_DIE_C 
fuelrecords_ID (foreign ID from fuelrecords) 

fuelrecords_pet 
FRP_ID (AUTO INCREMENT) 
FR_PET_L 
FR_PET_C 
fuelrecords_ID (foreign ID from fuelrecords) 

fuelrecords_oil 
FRO_ID (AUTO INCREMENT) 
FR_OIL_L 
FR_OIL_C 
fuelrecords_ID (foreign ID from fuelrecords)
```

Basically the purpose is to log vehicle fuel usage and cost. As there wont always be data for petrol, diesel and oil hence the separate tables so only needed dat is logged. 
Hope this clarifies

A always all help and assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: what ever you do, never post code with userids and passwords (mysql connection here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly you have 4 tables: `fuelrecords`, `fuelrecords_die`, `fuelrecords_pet`, `fuelrecords_oil`.

The 3 tables `fuelrecords_die`, `fuelrecords_pet`, `fuelrecords_oil` each have a foreign key `fuelrecords_id` to `fuelrecords.fr_id`.

You now want to insert multiple tuples into `fuelrecords` and, if additional data is provided, multiple tuples into the other 3 tables. I assume the `fuelrecords.fr_id` column is a auto incrementing primary key.

To insert multiple tuples into fuelrecords and to have them each have a new fr_id, you just don't pass a value for the column `fr_id`. This is equivalent to passing `NULL` as value. MySQL will then automatically insert unique consecutive numbers for each tuple.

After that you can call `mysql_insert_id()` to get the **first** inserted id. Using `mysql_affected_rows()` you can get the number of inserted tuples. This is enough information to get the id for all lastly inserted tuples. The first is `mysql_insert_id()+0` the second is `mysql_insert_id()+1`, ..., the last is `mysql_insert_id()+(mysql_affected_rows()-1)`.

In the next step you iterate over your input data again and insert the `fuelrecords_id` into each of the tuples for the other 3 tables, using the above mentioned method. If `$i` is the index of your input data `$_POST['FR_DIE_L'][$i]` (starting at `$i==0`), the `fuelrecords_id` will be `mysql_insert_id()+$i`. You are only allowed to iterate to `mysql_insert_id()+mysql_affected_rows()-1`, but you will probably have the same count of POST-data anyways.

A much simpler but slightly less efficient way is to just do one `insert into fuelrecords` and then one insert into the other 3 tables for each single POST-data object. You won't have to calculate the `fuelrecords_id` as `mysql_insert_id()` will give you the correct id after each insert.

```
<?php

$wedrf=trim($_POST['FR_WE']);
list($d, $m, $y) = explode('/', $wedrf);
$mk=mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, $d, $y);
$wed_refor=strftime('%Y-%m-%d',$mk);

$row_data = array(); 

// shorthand for mysql_real_escape_string
function esc($value) {
    return mysql_real_escape_string($value);
}

// all tuples for fuelrecords to be inserted
foreach($_POST['VEH_LIST_REG'] as $row => $VEH_LIST_REG) { 
    $row_data[] = "(NULL, '".esc($VEH_LIST_REG)."', '".esc($wed_refor)."')";
} 

if (!empty($row_data)) { 
    $query = 'INSERT INTO fuelrecords(FR_ID, VEH_LIST_REG, FR_WE) VALUES '.implode(',', $row_data);
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    # get first fuelrecord id  
    $first_fuelrecords_id = mysql_insert_id();

    // all tuples for the other 3 tables. insert only if data is givin.
    $die_data = array();
    $pet_data = array();
    $oil_data = array();
    foreach($_POST['VEH_LIST_REG'] as $row => $VEH_LIST_REG) {

        // calculate the right fuelrecords_id for this tuple
        $fuelrecords_id = (int)($first_fuelrecords_id + $row);

        // insert for fuelrecords_die
        if (isset($_POST['FR_DIE_L'][$row]))
        {
            $die_data[] = "(NULL, ".$fuelrecords_id.", '".esc($_POST['FR_DIE_L'][$row])."', '".esc($_POST['FR_DIE_C'][$row])."')";
        }

        // insert for fuelrecords_pet
        if (isset($_POST['FR_PET_L'][$row]))
        {
            $pet_data[] = "(NULL, ".$fuelrecords_id.", '".esc($_POST['FR_PET_L'][$row])."', '".esc($_POST['FR_PET_C'][$row])."')";
        }

        // insert for fuelrecords_oil
        if (isset($_POST['FR_OIL_L'][$row]))
        {
            $oil_data[] = "(NULL, ".$fuelrecords_id.", '".esc($_POST['FR_OIL_L'][$row])."', '".esc($_POST['FR_OIL_C'][$row])."')";
        }
    }

    // insert the tuples into fuelrecords_die
    if (!empty($die_data))
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO fuelrecords_die(FRD_ID, fuelrecords_ID, FR_DIE_L, FR_DIE_C) VALUES ".implode(',', $die_data);
        $result = mysql_query( $sql);
    }

    // insert the tuples into fuelrecords_pet
    if (!empty($pet_data))
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO fuelrecords_pet(FRP_ID, fuelrecords_ID, FR_PET_L, FR_PET_C) VALUES ".implode(',', $pet_data);
        $result = mysql_query( $sql);
    }

    // insert the tuples into fuelrecords_oil
    if (!empty($oil_data))
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO fuelrecords_oil(FRO_ID, fuelrecords_ID, FR_OIL_L, FR_OIL_C) VALUES ".implode(',', $oil_data);
        $result = mysql_query( $sql);
    }
}

?>
```

A small off-topic addition: Try not to use upper case variable names. Upper case identifiers are usually preserved for constants:

```
define("MY_SHORT_PI", 3.14159265);
define("MY_CONST", "foobar");

$my_variable = "bat";

echo "I am a constant ".MY_SHORT_PI;
echo "Me too ".MY_CONST;
echo "I am a variable ".$my_variable;
```

This won't have any effect on the PHP interpreter. It's just a common notation to make your code readable for others. There are many style guides out there like [the one from PEAR](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.php).

**Second Example (see comments)**

```
<?php

$wedrf=trim($_POST['FR_WE']);
list($d, $m, $y) = explode('/', $wedrf);
$mk=mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, $d, $y);
$wed_refor=strftime('%Y-%m-%d',$mk);

// VALUES strings for fuelrecords
$row_data = array();

// temporary storage for just _L and _C values
$die_data_tmp = array();
$pet_data_tmp = array();
$oil_data_tmp = array();

// VALUES strings for the three tables
$die_data = array();
$pet_data = array();
$oil_data = array();

// shorthand for mysql_real_escape_string
function esc($value) {
    return mysql_real_escape_string($value);
}

// all tuples for fuelrecords to be inserted
foreach($_POST['VEH_LIST_REG'] as $row => $VEH_LIST_REG) { 

    // check if diesel values are greater than 0
    if (0 < (int)$_POST['FR_DIE_L'][$row] && 0 < (int)$_POST['FR_DIE_C'][$row])
        $die_data_tmp[$row] = array($_POST['FR_DIE_L'][$row], $_POST['FR_DIE_C'][$row]);

    // check if petrolium values are greater than 0
    if (0 < (int)$_POST['FR_PET_L'][$row] && 0 < (int)$_POST['FR_PET_C'][$row])
        $pet_data_tmp[$row] = array($_POST['FR_PET_L'][$row], $_POST['FR_PET_C'][$row]);

    // check if oil values are greater than 0
    if (0 < (int)$_POST['FR_OIL_L'][$row] && 0 < (int)$_POST['FR_OIL_C'][$row])
        $oil_data_tmp[$row] = array($_POST['FR_OIL_L'][$row], $_POST['FR_OIL_C'][$row]);

    // check if at least one of the 3 tables will get tuples. if not just continue 
    // with the next and don't assign this fuelrecord tuple to $row_data
    if (! isset($die_data_tmp[$row]) && ! isset($pet_data_tmp[$row]) && ! isset($oil_data_tmp[$row]))
        continue;

    // all values are at least 1, so add this tuple to our inserts
    $row_data[$row] = "(NULL, '".esc($VEH_LIST_REG)."', '".esc($wed_refor)."')";
}

if (!empty($row_data)) { 
    $query = 'INSERT INTO fuelrecords(FR_ID, VEH_LIST_REG, FR_WE) VALUES '.implode(',', $row_data);
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    # get first fuelrecord id  
    $current_fuelrecords_id = mysql_insert_id();

    // all tuples for the other 3 tables. insert only if data is givin.
    foreach($row_data as $row => $VEH_LIST_REG) {

        // insert for fuelrecords_die
        if (isset($die_data_tmp[$row]))
        {
            $die_data[] = "(NULL, ".$current_fuelrecords_id.", '".esc($die_data_tmp[$row][0])."', '".esc($die_data_tmp[$row][1])."')";
        }

        // insert for fuelrecords_pet
        if (isset($pet_data_tmp[$row]))
        {
            $pet_data[] = "(NULL, ".$current_fuelrecords_id.", '".esc($pet_data_tmp[$row][0])."', '".esc($pet_data_tmp[$row][1])."')";
        }

        // insert for fuelrecords_oil
        if (isset($oil_data_tmp[$row]))
        {
            $oil_data[] = "(NULL, ".$current_fuelrecords_id.", '".esc($oil_data_tmp[$row][0])."', '".esc($oil_data_tmp[$row][1])."')";
        }

        // increment the fuelrecords_id for the next tuple.
        ++$current_fuelrecords_id;
    }

    // insert the tuples into fuelrecords_die
    if (!empty($die_data))
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO fuelrecords_die(FRD_ID, fuelrecords_ID, FR_DIE_L, FR_DIE_C) VALUES ".implode(',', $die_data);
        $result = mysql_query( $sql);
    }

    // insert the tuples into fuelrecords_pet
    if (!empty($pet_data))
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO fuelrecords_pet(FRP_ID, fuelrecords_ID, FR_PET_L, FR_PET_C) VALUES ".implode(',', $pet_data);
        $result = mysql_query( $sql);
    }

    // insert the tuples into fuelrecords_oil
    if (!empty($oil_data))
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO fuelrecords_oil(FRO_ID, fuelrecords_ID, FR_OIL_L, FR_OIL_C) VALUES ".implode(',', $oil_data);
        $result = mysql_query( $sql);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Added a long example. Code not tested, so beware of errors. ;-)

Comment: Code works well thank you at putting the fuel records id into the respective other tables.

My problem is stopping the blank entries from being added. Also I have just realised that some weeks a vehicle entry may not need to be made into the fuelrecords table if there are no records to be added into any of the other tables. I am guessing the best way to approach this is to make the code reliably not enter 0 into the tables and then address the issue with entries into fuel records if there is no data for any of the other tables.

Comment: You could just check `empty($_POST['FR_DIE_L'][$row])` etc before inserting.

Comment: You don't want to insert all tuples for the table `fuelrecords`? I would just unset the values `$_POST['FR_DIE_L'][$row]` etc for every `$row` you do not wish to insert. I can add an example to the answer if this is the problem.

Comment: I only want not to add certain tuples to fuel records if there are no records to be added to all of the other 3 tables for that row. in addition if you can assist in a validation rule to empty values in certain rows so i don't get 0's in my tables i would be grateful. would it assist to see my code that supplies the post data?

Comment: I added a second example to my answer. To not insert 0's in your table I checked if every value is at least 1. If all values for one of the three tables are "valid", they will be added to the respective array and inserted later. If for a `fuelrecords` tuple all three tables would be empty, this `fuelrecords` tuple will not be inserted. There might be more efficient or better readable solutions, but this will hopefully do the trick, as well. ;-)

Comment: Hi Basti, Apologies for the delay in getting back to you. I have now had chance to test the code. What I am finding is that if all three sets of data are available (oil,diesel and petrol) the entry is submitted perfectly. However if any one of the three are missing none of the values are stored. What I was working towards is that simply the zero values would not be stored with the rest of the row being stored where applicable. You have done an excellent job on this so far and if you dont mind getting me to the end of this I would be most grateful. Alan

Comment: Hey Burdie87. De Morgan strikes back. ;-) I made a change to the second example. It should know work if you provide data for only one or two of the three tables, as well. Line changed: `if (! isset($die_data_tmp[$row]) && ! isset($pet_data_tmp[$row]) && ! isset($oil_data_tmp[$row]))`